# Building a Data Feed Management Importer

Tags: php, mysql, xml, feed

I am building a comparing pricing website. I am using my custom made php software. What i have right now is a list of several electronic products. There is a list of max 50.000 products in my mysql database. All with EAN numbers.

So basically there are 30-50 websites who use product data feeds. Some of the clients has more than 15.000 products in the data feed. Some use XML with UTF and other flat XML. And other use CSV format data feeds.

I have manage to build a XML parser to read the product feed from 1 client who has more dan 12.000 products.

**My Code:**

```
$xml_pf_file = "product_datafeed.xml";

$local_feed = new ProgramIterator($xml_pf_file, $def_xml_path);

foreach ($local_feed as $feedClient) {

    $Price      = $feedClient[''.$def_price.''];                    
    $DeepLink   = $feedClient[''.$def_url.''];                  
    $EanNr      = $feedClient[''.$def_ean.''];


    if ((strlen($EanNr) > 8) && is_numeric($EanNr)) 
    {

        $ProductId = CheckEanNrInProductDatabase($EanNr);

        if ($ProductId > 0)
        {

            $sql_add = "INSERT INTO ProductsFeedPrices 
                        (ProductId, CustomerId, Price, Deeplink) VALUES
                        (".$ProductId.", ".$CustomerId.", ".$Price.", '".$DeepLink."') ";

            if (mysql_query($sql_add)) {
                $teller_add++;
            }

            $count_add++;

        }


    }

    $count_i++;

}
```

From outside each website uses there own type of product data feed (xml, csv, json). Sometimes even takes like 5 min for reading 1 product feed. I want to build a procedure that renders all the product feeds automatically in the mysql database with PHP -> EAN number is basic checkup for the existing products.

Is there a good way for recognizing the product feed types and can make custom edit for the import?

Comment: One known concept here is to encapsulate what varies. The other is to fail early. And a third one is that you have to look to get the data into the mysql fast so you don't need to care about the different formats any longer. But it's only comments because your question is off-topic for a Q&A site like Stackoverlow. Any answer you get will be opinionated with little use of the targeted future visitor.

Comment: My question is very simple! Is this the best solution? or are there other examples that works better?

Comment: Okay, fair saying. Simple question simple answer: There never is a best answer universally. So logic dictates the answer: No. For your second question on are there other examples that works better: Unlimited, most of them not yet written down.

Comment: This not really a solution answer. But thanx anyway.

Comment: It's less about the thanx, check the help section on how you can improve your question to get better answers and more traction: http://stackoverflow.com/help